# Element not interactable error for input element of type textbox selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use selenium to input a location into the search tab of weather.com. I initially wrote the code in Python and it's working as expected:

```
// this works
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.weather.com/')
time.sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('LocationSearch_input')
time.sleep(2)
elem.send_keys(location)
time.sleep(2)
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Now, I'm trying to translate this code into Javascript, but I keep getting an error "ElementNotInteractableError: element not interactable." I'm confused why this is happening since the same id tag works in my Python code, and when I inspect the webpage the element with that id is of type textbox.

```
    await driver.get('http://www.weather.com/');
    console.log("step0");
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@id="LocationSearch_input"]'));
    console.log("step1");
    await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@id="LocationSearch_input"]')).click();
    console.log("step2");
    await driver.findElement(By.className('//input[@id="LocationSearch_input"]')).sendKeys(location, Key.RETURN);
    console.log("step3");
```

The above code runs through step 2 and throws the error on the line before console.log("step3"). How can I properly translate the working Python code to JS?

Answer (score 0):

You're using findElement(By.className()) with an xpath as input so change that to By.xpath().
I don't know exactly what keys you're trying to send as input but the syntax is: .sendkeys("Your text here between quotes")

Change the last line to:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@id="LocationSearch_input"]')).sendKeys("text");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I just tried your code (I had the className as a residual typo - good catch) and I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas of how I could fix the problem?

Comment: Can you provide the html you're trying this on?

Comment: Here's the HTML element I'm trying to access:

<input role="textbox" id="LocationSearch_input" data-testid="searchModalInputBox" class="SearchInput--InputField--73wGA Search--inputClass--2Grs8" type="text" placeholder="Search City or Zip Code" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-describedby="SearchAccessibleHint" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="LocationSearch_listbox" aria-multiline="false" value="">

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with that, are you sure thats the only element with that id on the webpage?

Comment: Maybe add a sleep between step 2 and 3 to see if thats the problem since you have that in your python implementation?

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work...there is a parent label tag which has the same id, but I assumed that by using xpath I was clearing up any discrepancy/repetition. I can maybe use the python version except I'm trying to integrate this function as a click response on a webpage and I'm struggling to interface the python function with the JS/html of the rest of the page. any advice there? thanks for helping